# Using find() with arguments that will result in not finding anything results in the RAM never getting "dropped"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently setting up a mongodb and so far I have a DB with 25million objects, and some index. When I try use find() with 4 arguments and I know that one of the arguments are "wrong" or that the result of the query will be nothing found, then what happens is that mongodb takes all my RAM (8gb) and the time to get the "nothing found" varies a lot.

BUT the biggest problem is that once it's done it never lets go of the RAM and I need to restart mongodb to get back the RAM.

I've tried many other tests, such as adding huge amounts of objects (1million+), use the find() for something that I know exist and other operations and they work fine.

Also want to know that this works fine if I have a smaller DB like 1million objects.
I will keep on doing test on this, but if anyone have anything they know right away that could help that would be great.

EDIT: Tested some more with 1m DB. The first failed found took about 4sec and took some RAM, the proceding fails took only 0.6sec and didn't seem to affect the RAM. Does mongodb store the DB in RAM when trying to find a document and with very huge DB it can't get all in the cache?

Btw. on the 25mil it first took about 60sec to not find it, but the 2nd try took 174sec and after that find it had taken all the 8gb on RAM.

Comment: The OS by default does not release RAM. This is a costly and completely useless process. It is better instead to page out data when required. As to why MongoDB is exhausting your memory: try an explain and find out where the speed problems are

Comment: This is a little too broad and I for one am struggling to find the question in this. It's pretty normal behavior for most DBMS to load a "working set" to memory, and especially for a memory mapped system such as MongoDB. If you have a lot of variation then you get a lot of usage and paging. But still can't see the programming issue. Are you in fact a DBA asking "how do I get back the RAM?"

Comment: So would you simply say that 8gb of RAM is to little if you have a DB with 25mil objects? That I need more RAM in case the DB has to put more or less all of it in the working memory due to a search/find that won't find anything?

Comment: I would say instead that your timings are most likely lack of indexes that support your queries along with probably quite large documents which is causing page thrashing. Also loading 25m objects from disk might also be creating a IO bottleneck

Comment: As for the RAM: MongoDB keeps as much of the working set in RAM as possible. Unused RAM is _bad_ RAM.

Comment: Markus of course unused RAM is bad, but the problem I have is that mongodb takes ALL of the RAM and then the computer becomes very very slow and I'm force to restart mongodb.

Well I think it is like Sammaye is talking about that might be index problems, I've been trying some different indexes, and right now I'm in a phase of just trying to test everything and noticed this problem.

While this might be a different subject, but how would you setup your indexes, if you have a find that takes 4 different arguments. Just use ensureindex on all of those indexes?

Comment: Best to ask a separate question for that, including sample documents and queries.